# Como faço para parar o For quando o range for 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como faço para interromper o ciclo For quando o atingir uma certa condição ?
Para o exemplo, seria quando o c for igual a 5.

```
for c in range(1,10):
    print('a,b,c')

if c % 5:
    break
```

Depois, irá ser utilizado uma função, porém gostaria de entender o controle de fluxo no python.

Comment: não é melhor só fazer `range(1, 5)`?

Comment: `range(0,10)` para fazer break no `5` incondicionalmente não tem sentido

Comment: Isto parece um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy). Melhor seria tentar explicar o que está realmente a tentar fazer e preferêncialmente com código real, para que fique claro para todos.

Comment: Agora a pergunta mudou, o que piorou a situação. Tem uma resposta e aceita, então mudar a pergunta a torna inválida., não pode fazer isto.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ola, voce pode usar assim:

```
for c in range(1,10):
    print('a,b,c')
    if c % 5:  # Condição 
       break
```

O **if c == 5:** tem de estar dentro do ciclo **for**.

Caso deseje pular somente um ciclo você pode usar o **continue** no lugar do **break**.

#### Extra :

Como vi nos comentarios em cima, você quer utilizar uma função quando chegar em um certo valor.

- *Atenção : não faria sentido interromper o ciclo **for** para um **range**, pois você poderia usar desta forma:*

  ```
  for c in range(1,x):
          print('a,b,c')
  ```

  - *Agora o **x** será a condição de parada. "Evitando o uso do **if**" .*

O código da pergunta pode ficar assim:

```
def funcaoStack(): # Função de exemplo, que será chamada dentro do ciclo do FOR.
    print('foo!!!')

def funcaoOverflow(): # Função de exemplo, que será chamada após o ciclo FOR.
    print('saa!!!')

for i in range(10):

    if i % 5: # Essa fução irá ser chamada quando i for igual a 5.
        funcaoStack()
        continue # Foi adicionado o "continue" para demonstração. 

    if i == 7: # Aqui o ciclo FOR será interrompido, ai continua o'que está no script. 
        break

    print(i) # Por que o "print" está depois do "if" ?
             # Pois para fazer sentido na resposta, primeiro se verifica as condições no ciclo.

funcaoOverflow()
```

Comment: Isto não faz o menor sentido, apesar de funcionar.

Comment: @Maniero acho que faz sentido porque fundamentalmente a questão é "como parar o loop for quando uma certa condição for atingida", e a condição ser `c == 5` é só o caso mais fácil/óbvio. Uma boa resposta explicaria como fazer, e também o porque de não ser uma boa ideia.

Comment: @Maniero também não acho boa prática responder uma pergunta e depois fechar ela.

Comment: @M Editei a minha resposta para que tenha mais sentido, com um exemplo de utilização.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig E fazer isto não faz sentido, nenhum zentido, zero. Este site foi concebido para ensinar as pessoas programarem melhor, para resolver problemas reais, não para fazer códigos sem sentido, então a pergunta e esta resposta é um desserviço. Garanto que muita gente verá isto e achará que é o certo a se fazer, ainda hoje que as pessoas não querem ver contexto. É lamentável e um descredito para o site ter algo assim. Ensinar errado nunca é algo bom.

Comment: @DaviMello como a pergunta não faz sentido eu apaguei. Eu achei que era um pergunta onde se esperava uma resposta correta e que pudesse aprender algo correto.

Comment: Caro @PedrovonHertwig acho que ele não fechou exatamente após responder, ele respondeu acreditando que a pergunta era um código do qual poderia "ser melhorado", quero dizer, eu concordo, um `break` para um `range` não faz muito sentido, então ele tentou mostrar um caminho "melhor", o AP comentou de volta mas não apresentou motivos para o porque justamente usou "RANGE"... tipo, isso é uma simulação de entrada de dados? Ou isso é confusão do AP? Não esta claro, então como AP não clareou o motivo ele fechou devidamente "não esta claro" [...]

Comment: [...] @PedrovonHertwig uma coisa que vejo que as pessoas ainda não entendem, fechar não é a mesma coisa que deletar para sempre, quase tudo que é fechado é apenas para evitar respostas precipitadas, se fechou pode ser reaberto a qualquer momento, o fechar é o momento oportuno para o AP editar e clarear a sua pergunta, recomendo que leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 ... Espero que eu tenha conseguido lhes dar um norte e espero que a pergunta possa ser "salva" assim que o AP clarear a necessidade disto.

Comment: Aproveito para complementar que o `if` incondicional no `5` e no `7` em ambos os exemplos não fazem sentido. É o mesmo que eu abastecer gasolina no carro para fazer 300 Km mas sei que aos 100km vou sair da estrada e chegar ao meu destino.

Comment: @Isac ;  Pronto, mudei a resposta para ficar fazendo sentido para todos.

Comment: Agora não tem mais o que salvar aqui, eu errei, eu deveria ter fechado desde o início, tinha indícios que seria um problema, mas o pessoal reclama que fecho muito rápido, aqui está uma mostra porque fecho rápido, teria poupado todo o problema. Com o fechamento e cuidado quem sabe saísse algo bom disso.

Comment: @Maniero ; sou novo no stack, mas o problema está na pergunta ou na minha resposta ? E como poderia ser feito certo ?

Comment: Principalmente na pergunta, mas a resposta acaba indo por um caminho complicado que leva as pessoas a erro. Na verdade o mais certo seria fechar isto como "não é uma pegunta real", mas esse motivo não existe mais. veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. precisa ser um problema prático, real, algo que bisque o correto. Aqui a gente tenta considerar boa fé até que se prove o contrário. Querer aprender o certo mesmo que de forma atrapalhada tudo bem, mas ficou claro que não era o que queria, e ñ manteve mente aberta pra uma solução diferente